# Migrate IIS sites across servers

Tags: iis, msdeploy, windows-server

I need to migrate multiple IIS sites from one server to another. The problem here is that the target server already has IIS installed and some other sites running on it. All the solutions described in search results are unacceptable – they will replace everything basically doing a full wipe of the existing sites. Is there any way to create an "additive" migration package?​

Comment: If you migrate site by site, I don't think "full wipe" happens.

Comment: do you mean manually doing so? If yes - that's not a good option, there are 300+ sites to migrate

Answer (score 0):

You can use msdeploy.exe to sync individual sites between servers.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webServer -dest:webServer,computerName=Server2
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569005(v=ws.10).aspx